# Cannot receive any notification in my iphone4s from simulator

Tags: ios, push-notification, sinch

I tried to use SinchService to test the remote notification. I did all the steps as per the tutorial [IOS INSTANT MESSAGING USING SINCHSERVICE](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/ios-instant-messaging-using-sinchservice/). And when I tested it by sending a message from the simulator to my iphone, I cannot receive any notification, I tried many times but still cannot make it, can anybody help me out?

Comment: in simulator you can't get any notification.if you want to check notification then you need install app in two  device..then check you got notfication

Comment: But the tutorial says "Note that push notification will only work on devices. If you're using a simulator, try sending a push message from your simulator to your device."

Comment: apple says push notification not work on simulator

Comment: Apple push notification only works on device because you not get device token in simulator and without device token can't get notification.

Comment: mail support@sinch.com and share your project, its probably a capabilities issues on your project. from simulator to phone should work

Answer (score 0):

Remote notification not work on simulator. try to test on device it works on only device use [This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) demo for more information it contain php file that run on cmd to send notification to device.